# SVG to After Effects workflow?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, vector-graphics, adobe-after-effects

I have a JavaScript chart component that outputs SVG. (It's kind of like an animated bar chart with a time slider.)

One of my clients would like to customize this animation further in After Effects - perhaps add some other background colors, depth etc.

**What would be a good workflow for this?**

*(Let's say the timespan of the visualization is 30 years.
I could easily save one SVG file per year - then open these in illustrator. Resave the files as .ai for import into After Effects. Then I think After Effects can understand that this is a range of layered files and space the SVGs evenly on the timeline? Can it also add motion tweens inbetween the "years" for the vector objects (if each layer only has one object) to make the animation even smoother?)*